# How to read and print PKI Attributes such as Common Name in Java

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat

How can I making a webpage that prints visitors Common Name (CN).

I tried using a servlet filter. I am unable to read my PKI credentials.I need to store this in a session. Then print to html page.

I have an FilterConstant.java interface I want to print the values detected through the webpage.

public interface FilterConstants {

public static final String JSESSON_ID = "JSESSION_ID";
public static final String USER_CN_ATTR = "SSL_CLIENT_DN";

I am trying to figure out how to print the actual values of the CN that is visiting the index.html site.

Comment: `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`

Comment: That just prints null

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question was to make sure the x509 and ssl mods were in the apache configuration files, then apache sets that inside the session and it becomes in scope for you to use programmatically in the browser session when talking about a web application.